# Finding substring duplication in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

TableA contains many records where col1 field is duplicated  for the first six characters.

col1 contains:  football  and footbcuu   and footbcavity

I need to find all the rows where the first five characters are duplicated.

```
SELECT * FROM tableaA A WHERE 
rowid > 
(SELECT min(rowid) FROM tableA B 
WHERE B.substr (col1, 1, 5)= A.substr (col1, 1, 5));
```

errors with unexpected end of statement, and I think it just about the brackets.

Can someone help with this syntax?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the syntax errors, I don't understand the logic in your attempt.

The following query gets all rows where the first five characters are duplicated:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*, count(*) over (partition by substr(a.col1, 1, 5)) as cnt
      from tableA a
     ) a
where cnt > 1
order by a.col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see one missing bracket right at the end of statement

```
SELECT * FROM tableaA A WHERE 
rowid > 
(SELECT min(rowid) FROM tableA B 
WHERE B.substr (col1, 1, 5)= A.substr (col1, 1, 6));
```

Comment: You've copied the typo from the OP's code.  A string of five characters is never going to equal a string of six.

Comment: edited to fix typo and I had the extra bracket in the original... still getting end of statement